# How to manage Android toolbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, toolbar

I'm working on an app where I've put an android widget.toolbar as supportActionBar, but I couldn't find anything on how to manage its properties. I would like, for example, to modify and add elements in the overflow menu (I don't know if the name is correct at all, however I mean the one that appears when you click the 3-points default icon on the right corner. I'll post an image.) and to set a listener for each one of them.

[image: I would like to add something else in addition to "Settings" and manage the clicking on each item.]

Comment: You can learn about toolbar [here](http://androhub.com/android-toolbar/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the menu you have to follow the old implementation. You add an item inside the res/menu/your_menu.xml, you specify an action and you manage the action inside the `onOptionsItemSelected()` of your Activity or Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example:

In activity :

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        //Title and subtitle
        toolbar.setTitle("MY toolbar");
        toolbar.setSubtitle("Subtitle");

        //Menu
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.toolbar_menu);

        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {

                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.action_share:
                        Toast.makeText(ToolbarActivity.this,"Share",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

In XML file :

Create xml file like normal option menu :

toolbar_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="example.gmariotti.it.test21.ToolbarActivity" >

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_share"
          android:title="@string/action_share"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />


    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```